# JavaScript Object Literal "this" keyword jQuery Callbacks Argument Passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this, object-literal

What am I doing wrong here? I'm super frustrated here.    I'm stuck @ when I call Menu.mouseHandler and since it's being passed an argument it seems to lose its value of this?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/W6KsU/19/

```
var Menu = Menu || {};

Menu = {
    docHeight: jQuery("document").height(),
    menuOffset: jQuery("#menu").offset(),
    index:0,
    menuItem:"",
    menuItemName:"",
    menuItemPure:"",
    killMenu: function () {
        jQuery.each(['#menuApplyForCredit', '#menuBuyOrLease', '#menuVehicleProtection', '#menuCommercialFinancing', '#menuFinanceTools'], function () {
            jQuery(menuItem).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave", function () {
                console.log("NO CLICK! DO NOTHING~");
            });
        });
    },

    initialize: function () {
        if (jQuery.browser.ios) {
            jQuery.each(['#menuApplyForCredit', '#menuBuyOrLease', '#menuVehicleProtection', '#menuCommercialFinancing', '#menuFinanceTools'], this.touchHandler);
        } else {
            jQuery.each(['#menuApplyForCredit', '#menuBuyOrLease', '#menuVehicleProtection', '#menuCommercialFinancing', '#menuFinanceTools'], this.mouseHandler);
        }
    },

    touchHandler: function (i, v) {
        var _that = this,
        this.index = i;
        this.menuItem = v;
        this.menuItemPure = menuItem.replace('#menu', '');
        jQuery(menuItem).bind("touchstart touchend", _that.onTouch);
    },

    mouseHandler: function (i, v) {
        this.index = i;
        this.menuItem = v;
        console.log("mouseHandler: menuItem= "+this.menuItem);
        this.menuItemName = jQuery(this.menuItem).find("a:first img").attr("src");
        this.menuItemPure = this.menuItem.replace('#menu', '');

        console.log("menuItemName=" + this.menuItemName);
        console.log("menuItemPure=" + this.menuItemPure);

        jQuery(this.menuItem).bind("mouseenter", Menu.onEnter);
        //console.log(jQuery(this.menuItem).bind("mouseenter", Menu.onEnter))
        //jQuery(this.menuItem).bind("mouseenter", jQuery.proxy(Menu.onEnter, Menu));
        jQuery(this.menuItem).bind("mouseleave", jQuery.proxy(Menu.onLeave, Menu));
    },

    onEnter: function () {
          console.log("CALLED!");
        //console.log("evt= "+this);
        //console.log("this= "+this);
        //console.log("onEnter menuItem= " + menuItem);
        jQuery('#menu_overlay').clearQueue().stop().css({
            'display': 'block'
        }).animate({
            opacity: '.3'
        }, 200).height(this.docHeight);
        //console.log("onEnter menuItemPure= "+ menuItemPure);
        jQuery("#megaMenu" + menuItemPure + "Div").addClass("hovering");
        jQuery(menuItem).find("a:first").find("img").attr("src", "images/bttn" + menuItemPure + "Over.png").css({
            "z-index": "99"
        });
    },

    onLeave: function () {
        var _that = this;
        console.log("onLeave= "+ menuItem);
        var relX = Math.round(evt.pageX - this.menuOffset.left),
            relY = evt.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        if ((relX < 960 && relX > 0) && (relY < 41 && relY > 0)) {
            jQuery("#megaMenu" + menuItemPure + "Div").removeClass("hovering");
            if (menuItemName.indexOf("Stay") > -1) {
                jQuery(menuItem).find("a:first").find("img").attr("src", "images/bttn" + menuItemPure + "Stay.png").css({
                    "z-index": "1"
                });
            } else {
                jQuery(menuItem).find("a:first").find("img").attr("src", "images/bttn" + menuItemPure + ".png").css({
                    "z-index": "1"
                });
            }
        } else {
            jQuery('#menu_overlay').css({
                'display': 'none'
            }).animate({
                opacity: '0'
            }, 100);
            jQuery("#megaMenu" + menuItemPure + "Div").removeClass("hovering");
            if (menuItemName.indexOf("Stay") > -1) {
                jQuery(menuItem).find("a:first").find("img").attr("src", "images/bttn" + menuItemPure + "Stay.png").css({
                    "z-index": "1"
                });
            } else {
                jQuery(menuItem).find("a:first").find("img").attr("src", "images/bttn" + menuItemPure + ".png").css({
                    "z-index": "1"
                });
            }
        }
    },

    onTouch: function () {
        jQuery('#menu_overlay').clearQueue().stop().hide().css({
            'display': 'block'
        }).animate({
            opacity: '.3'
        }, 200).height(this.docHeight);
        jQuery("#megaMenu" + menuItemPure + "Div").removeClass("hovering").addClass("hovering");
        jQuery(menuItem).find("a:first").find("img").attr("src", "images/bttn" + menuItemPure + "Over.png").css({
            'z-index': '99'
        });
    }
}

Menu.initialize();
```

Comment: Typo under `touchHandler`, `var _that = this,` <- terminate with semicolon.

Comment: What are you actually accomplishing / trying to accomplish by assigning to properties of `this` in `mouseHandler`? Those properties are just being reassigned on each iteration / invocation of the callback.

Comment: Yes I see that.  I'm trying accomplish keeping alive the iterating / invoking down the chain of methods. Maybe this is the wrong approach to this but I'm just working it out.

Comment: I'm not positive I know what you mean, but if you mean where you're attaching `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` in `mouseHandler`, those listeners are being bound to the DOM elements that your selectors (the `v` argument to `mouseHandler`) refer to. If you're trying to make sure `this` refers to `Menu` in `onEnter` / `onLeave`, use `jQuery.proxy`, which I see you're already doing in one place. If you want `this` to refer to `Menu` in `mouseHandler`, see my answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W6KsU/22/  - Yes, I guess I understand the proxy'ing to refer to this, but yes I'm having trouble keeping on to onEnter and binding those events to those methods while passing the iterative value "v" as menuItem to the jQuery object.   jQuery(menuItem) //undefined.   Do I need to proxy that as well?

Comment: What exactly do you get when you call `jQuery(menuItem)`? Is it really `undefined`? Even if there's a problem with the selector, you should get a jQuery object with an empty set. Is jQuery definitely loaded when you set `Menu`? Is the DOM loaded when you call `Menu.initialize();`? E.g. does that code run in a `$( document ).ready()` handler, or after the HTML that defines the `#menu*` elements in source order? Are you able to post a complete JSfiddle with HTML? BTW, maybe goes without saying, but you could just do `mouseHandler: function ( index, menuItem )` if you want.

Comment: Yeah you are exactly right on the selector empty set and the problem is I forgot to wrap the method call in a dom ready wrapper. I took this code from its overall context and it totally slipped my mind!!  Doh! Yes  it does go without saying passing in arguments (i, menuItem) but I was thinking that since I need to pass these arguments again (onEnter) I should store the values somehow.?  Ofcourse onEnter appears to have lost iteration.   Yes I will post a full jsfiddle /W6KsU/25/ but, take a look here I put up a stand-alone page here @ http://www.moeaso.com/menu

Comment: Well, for `onEnter` you'll probably want to have it accept an argument, I'll call it `event`, and then access `event.currentTarget`. For something like `menuItemPure`, if you're accessing that in multiple methods you'll probably want to do something like store those values in a Menu.items object that maps `menuItem` values to other data, like `menuItemPure`, or use `jQuery.data()` to store those values with the DOM objects that the `menuItem` values correspond to.

Comment: right so not sure how I would use data in this case, but as you can see I'm passing the same values in different methods and trying to keep them along to keep up the iteration all the way on to onLeave.   So besides taking away the iteration to start how could I accomplish this?   menu options would need to be stored as array? again I need to pass in i, menuItem to mouseHandler, onEnter and also to onLeave

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7353/discussion-between-bradford-sherrill-and-jmm)

Answer (score 1):

With your code, `this` should refer to the value of the current item of the array you pass as the first argument.  If you want `this` to refer to `Menu`, try:

```
jQuery.each(

  [

    '#menuApplyForCredit',

    '#menuBuyOrLease',

    '#menuVehicleProtection',

    '#menuCommercialFinancing',

    '#menuFinanceTools'

  ],

  jQuery.proxy( this.mouseHandler, this )

);
```

See [jQuery.each() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

> In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword

And see the docs for the `jQuery.proxy( function, context )` version of [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).